# Root path of site in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, path

I am using Uploading Class to upload images. But the location where my uploaded images will be stored is: `http://www.mysite.com/uploads/`

Absolute path to this folder is: `c:\wamp\www\mysite\uploads\`

Application folder is in : `c:\wamp\www\mysite\application\`

So when I upload to server, absolute path will not be same. So, how to get absolute root path to use with the `upload_path` config of Uploading Class?

Comment: Use realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/');

Comment: $uploadpath=<?php echo base_url('uploads');?>

Answer (score 7):

This is coming late but the right path is:

```
FCPATH.'uploads';
```

Answer (score 1):

If the uploads folder is in the root of your site then you can simply use `./uploads` in your upload path configuration.

```
$config['upload_path'] = "./uploads";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use APPPATH you will get the directory path of your site root directory.

like this APPPATH.'uploads/images/';